# Can someone direct me to a script

Tags: javascript

Stack overflow has this very cool char counter under the comment box. Can someone direct me to the script? or a something slightly different

Comment: Choosing "View Source" from the context menu of pretty much any browser will let you get the scripts. If you want/need more, you can use firefox w/ firebug to better isolate them.

Answer (score 1):

The is a whole bunch of those at the [jQuery plugin repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/character-counter).